# How to distinguish zero from undefined in if condition?

Tags: c++, undefined, zero

```
    int todayPrice
cout << "Enter the price of the item this year:\n";
                cin >> todayPrice;
    if ( todayPrice == 0 ) {
            throw DIVIDED_BY_ZERO;
        } else if ( todayPrice < 0 ) {
            throw LESS_THAN_ZERO;
        } else if ( !todayPrice ) {
            throw NOT_A_NUM;
        }
```

If a user enters a zero or a string(which will be undefined I guess), it will evaluates to "number == 0", and they both throw DIVIDED_BY_ZERO exception.

How can I distinguish that the todayPrice is undefined(when a user enters a string) but not 0??

Comment: +1 I've got no idea why this has been downvoted twice. Maybe it's a far-too-basic question but it's still a valid question. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Leo It's vague, and the title isn't helpful or descriptive.

Comment: +1 because it's not vague, at all. The code and the text make it perfectly clear what the OP is trying to do. And coming up with good titles isn't always easy.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley well done mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the users enters anything but an integer, then the input stream will enter a failed state, which you can check with the stream:

```
if (std::cin >> todayPrice)
{
    // Do your other checks
}
else
{
    // User entered something that wasn't a valid integer
    std::cout << "Not a valid integer input\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You check if the input was successful:

```
if (cin >> num)
```